# How to underline a link in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a r markdown script to create a word document and I am pulling need to include a series of hyperlinks. However the links end up looking very similar to Word headings and I've been told to underline them to help distinguish.

my current code is something like this:
`[dat$title](dat$link)`

and I've tried
`[dat$title](dat$link){.underline}` and `[dat$title]{.underline}(dat$link)`
but the first doesn't work and the second ends up printing the url alongside the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the link inside a `<span>`-element and specify the `style`-attribute like so:

`<span style="text-decoration:underline"> [title](link) </span>`.